# Ethernet capture using packet_mmap gets much more packets than wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, ethernet, pcap, packet-capture

I have a c++ program which is capturing ethernet packets. I am using PACKET_MMAP settings in kernel. Which basically means I am calling socket api as below

socket(PF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));

I then read packets from the kernel ring buffer mmaped to user land using the TPACKET_V1 kernel api. I convert it to pcap format and store this in a file.

Before running the program, I also run wireshark to capture packets from all interfaces. After this I store the wireshark capture in pcap file.

Both my program and wireshark are started and stopped at together. I m controlling the packets on network too. Basically I am only sending a single ping packet to google.com . Wireshark captures the correct and right packets (at least that is what I can see from wireshark UI). However the size of file captured by wireshark vs my program is quite different. My program's captured file is almost 5 to 10 times larger than that captured by wireshark.

Is there any filtering my program should be doing before dumping packets in to file?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct pcap_hdr_s {
  uint32_t magic_number;   /* magic number */
  uint16_t version_major;  /* major version number */
  uint16_t version_minor;  /* minor version number */
  int32_t  thiszone;       /* GMT to local correction */
  uint32_t sigfigs;        /* accuracy of timestamps */
  uint32_t snaplen;        /* max length of captured packets, in octets */
  uint32_t network;        /* data link type */
} pcap_hdr_t;

typedef struct pcaprec_hdr_s {
  uint32_t ts_sec;         /* timestamp seconds */
  uint32_t ts_usec;        /* timestamp microseconds */
  uint32_t incl_len;       /* number of octets of packet saved in file */
  uint32_t orig_len;       /* actual length of packet */
} pcaprec_hdr_t;

FILE* pcapfile;

void handle_frame(struct tpacket_hdr* tphdr, struct sockaddr_ll* addr, char* l2content, char * l3content){

  pcaprec_hdr_t hdr;
  hdr.ts_sec = ntohl(tphdr->tp_sec);
  hdr.ts_usec = ntohl(tphdr->tp_usec);
  hdr.incl_len = tphdr->tp_snaplen;
  hdr.orig_len = tphdr->tp_len;

  fwrite(&hdr,sizeof(hdr),1,pcapfile);
  fwrite(l2content,tphdr->tp_snaplen,1,pcapfile);
}

int main(){
  pcapfile = fopen("pcapfile.pcap","a+");

  pcap_hdr_t hdr;
  hdr.magic_number = 0xa1b2c3d4;
  hdr.version_major = 0x02;
  hdr.version_minor = 0x04;
  hdr.thiszone = 0;
  hdr.sigfigs = 0;
  hdr.snaplen = 524288;
  hdr.network = 1;

  fwrite(&hdr,sizeof(hdr),1,pcapfile);

int fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
if (fd == -1) {
  perror("socket");
  exit(1);
 }

struct tpacket_req req = {0};
req.tp_frame_size = TPACKET_ALIGN(TPACKET_HDRLEN + ETH_HLEN) + TPACKET_ALIGN(1500);
req.tp_block_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
while (req.tp_block_size < req.tp_frame_size) {
  req.tp_block_size <<= 1;
 }
 req.tp_block_nr = 4;
size_t frames_per_buffer = req.tp_block_size / req.tp_frame_size;
req.tp_frame_nr = req.tp_block_nr * frames_per_buffer;

 int version = TPACKET_V1;
  (setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_VERSION, &version, sizeof(version));

 setsockopt(fd, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_RX_RING, (void*)&req, sizeof(req));

size_t rx_ring_size = req.tp_block_nr * req.tp_block_size;
char* rx_ring = mmap(0, rx_ring_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

struct pollfd fds[1] = {0};
fds[0].fd = fd;
fds[0].events = POLLIN;
size_t frame_idx = 0;
char* frame_ptr = rx_ring;

while (1) {
  struct tpacket_hdr* tphdr = (struct tpacket_hdr*)frame_ptr;
  while (!(tphdr->tp_status & TP_STATUS_USER)) {
    if (poll(fds, 1, -1) == -1) {
      perror("poll");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  struct sockaddr_ll* addr = (struct sockaddr_ll*)(frame_ptr + TPACKET_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
  char* l2content = frame_ptr + tphdr->tp_mac;
  char* l3content = frame_ptr + tphdr->tp_net;
  handle_frame(tphdr, addr, l2content, l3content);

  frame_idx = (frame_idx + 1) % req.tp_frame_nr;
  int buffer_idx = frame_idx / frames_per_buffer;
  char* buffer_ptr = rx_ring + buffer_idx * req.tp_block_size;
  int frame_idx_diff = frame_idx % frames_per_buffer;
  frame_ptr = buffer_ptr + frame_idx_diff * req.tp_frame_size;
 }

fflush(pcapfile);
fclose(pcapfile);
}
```

Comment: What are the extra packets your program is captures? Is it multiple copies of the same packets of additional packets you weren't expecting?

Comment: Since you already save your file to pcap, you can just open it in Wireshark and compare. Are there different packets inside? Why did you compare only the file size?

Comment: Thank @jwbensley maxy . I see the pcap file generated by my program under wireshark and I see many duplicate packets. I run my program when sending a single ping packet to google.com and my program captures lots of DNS queries and response and many of these are duplicates.

Comment: The source IP for these duplicate DNS packets is 127.0.0.1 and destination IP is 127.0.0.53 .  And btw, the name server on my /etc/resolv.conf is 127.0.0.53 . So basically my localhost (127.0.0.1) is sending DNS query to name server 127.0.0.53 about google.com . does this make sense? and would this be captured in kernel ring buffer through packet_mmap ?

Comment: @msgboardpana when asking a question here you need to post the code, we can't diagnose the problem because we have no context without the code. What interface have you bound the listening raw socket to?

Comment: @jwbensley just added the code

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. I have to check for TP_STATUS_USER before storing the packet to file. Not everything that kernel provides is fresh. Only when tp_status member of packer_hdr (declaration inside linux/if_packet.h) has value of TP_STATUS_USER it means that the packet is usable in application layer, otherwise kernel is not ready for application layer to use the packet.